# Unit test fails saying 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'city'

Tags: python, django

I have written a unit test to test an api....Its a GET call....
When I run it , i get this error ...Heres the traceback....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arindam31/XXX-Name/mapi/tests.py", line 141, in test_get_cities
    response = self.cl.get('/mapi/latest/cities/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 445, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 229, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 387, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 84, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/home/arindam31/XXX-Name/saul/views.py", line 546, in do_handle_500
    return render_to_response("500.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.update(processor(request))
  File "/home/arindam31/XXX-Name/saul/context_processors.py", line 46, in common_context
    ret_dict['city'] = request.city
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'city'
```

Heres my unit test...

```
def test_get_cities(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.city = self.c1
    response = self.cl.get('/mapi/latest/cities/')
    content = response.content
    data = json.loads(content)
    for city in City.objects.all():
        assert city.name in data
        assert data[city.name] == city.pk
```

Here , self.c1 is a city type object in the setUp part....HttpRequest is from django.http.

The view being tested is below:

```
def get_cities(request): 
    print "1"
    if ENABLE_HTTPS_CHECK and not request.is_secure():
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    if request.method != 'GET':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed('Not allowed')
    city_map = _get_city_map()
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(city_map)
    content_type='application/json')
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    return response
```

Comment: It's self.c1.....A city type object....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test your view with your own request object, you should call the view directly. You should use the [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.client.RequestFactory) to create your request.

As Daniel Roseman points out your request object having a city attribute remains broken, unless you have some middleware that would set it.  You clearly have some middleware that require it to be set in `saul/context_processors.py`.

Using `RequestFactory` and calling the view directly circumvents the middleware entirely, so you can concentrate on testing your view (if the view supports the absent middleware).

If your view requires the middelware to be operational, you probably just need to be logged in using the test client. It has a session pr test method.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what you are trying to do here. You instantiate a request object, assign a city attribute, then proceed to ignore that object and just use the standard test client. I don't know why you would think that that request would be used for the client get.

To be honest though I think that your entire design is broken. You don't show how you expect to get the parameter into the request in a normal non-test scenario, but usually you would pass it via the POST or GET parameters rather than annotating it into the request somehow. That would of course make it easier to test, since you could just pass the dictionary to the client call.

Comment: Since city attribute was not found , so I thought that I need to make a request object myself....so I make the request object ...now the get call needs no parameter to be passed...it's a straight call...now I don't understand how can I provide a request object with city...I thot of this way but that does not work...

Comment: Why don't you show your view? Then we'll know how that is expecting the city parameter. But again, in your code above you are not doing anything with the request.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry for the late response...Heres the view...
def get_cities(request):
  59     print "1"
  60     if ENABLE_HTTPS_CHECK and not request.is_secure():
  61         print '2'
  62         return HttpResponseForbidden()
  63     if request.method != 'GET':
  64         print '3'
  65         return HttpResponseNotAllowed('Not allowed')
  66     city_map = _get_city_map()
  67     print '4'
  68     response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(city_map),
  69             content_type='application/json')
  70     response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
  71     return response

I added the print